# Flatten Array and Discard Nested Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I am trying to flatten an array ***while also*** discarding values from the nested arrays.

Input:

```
[
  ["E:", 6533960335360],
  ["J:", 4493794811904],
  ["I:", 4407296360448],
  ["F:", 3380793327616],
  ["G:", 3212201390080],
  ["H:", 1704758915072],
  ["C:", 440328122368],
  ["K:", 54324703232],
  ["D:", 188514304]
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  "E:",
  "J:",
  "I:",
  "F:",
  "G:",
  "H:",
  "C:",
  "K:",
  "D:"
]
```

I know I can flatten the array with `[].concat.apply([], nestedArray)`, but is there a proper way to discard the unwanted items in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just map the values.

```js
var array = [["E:", 6533960335360], ["J:", 4493794811904], ["I:", 4407296360448], ["F:", 3380793327616], ["G:", 3212201390080], ["H:", 1704758915072], ["C:", 440328122368], ["K:", 54324703232], ["D:", 188514304]]
    result = array.map(([value]) => value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map()` and return the 1st item of each sub-array:

```js
const data = [["E:",6533960335360],["J:",4493794811904],["I:",4407296360448],["F:",3380793327616],["G:",3212201390080],["H:",1704758915072],["C:",440328122368],["K:",54324703232],["D:",188514304]]

const result = data.map(([v]) => v)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

You could use a map/array casting transformation since your data is already in a transposable format.

```
[...new Map(data).keys()]
```

or without the `spread` operator

```
Array.from( new Map(data).keys() );
```

```js
let data=[["E:",6533960335360],["J:",4493794811904],["I:",4407296360448],["F:",3380793327616],["G:",3212201390080],["H:",1704758915072],["C:",440328122368],["K:",54324703232],["D:",188514304]];

let result = [...new Map(data).keys()];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: is this method quicker/more efficient than using the `map` method?

Comment: @oldboy I'd imagine that a straight Array `map` *might* be faster, though the difference is likely negligible. It's simply a usable, alternative method than what has been posted.